# Navigatin bar color changes to black on pressing back button in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have two view controllers. First view controller is added on window in which the navigation bar is hidden. From there I load another view controller which has a blue navigation bar and is not hidden. On pressing the back button the color of this navigation bar changes to black before hiding. What should I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide navigation bar you must be doing this

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Apply this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  

     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Oh.. I got it now.. The mistkae was animated:NO, now I changed it to animated YES and it solved the problem.. thanks.. sometimes these small things haper progress!!